# Different Behavior for const int and int in C++ template

Tags: c++, templates, static-cast, explicit-conversion

When I use C++ template, I found that sometimes it gives a non-straightforward result.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template<class f0>
void func(const int& a1, f0& a2)
{
    std::cout << a1 + a2 << '\n';
    return;
}

template<class f0, class f1>
void func(f0& a1, f1& a2)
{
    std::cout << a1 - a2 << '\n';
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int bb = 3;
    int bbb = 3;
    func(static_cast<const int &>(bb), bbb); // 6
    func(bb, bbb); // 0
    func((int)bb, bbb); // 6
    
    func(static_cast<int &>(bb), bbb); // 0
    func(static_cast<int>(bb), bbb); // 6
    return 0;
}
```

When I pass an integer to first argument, It was recognized as a difference against `const int &`. However, when I re-pack it to `int`. I select the template of `const int&`.

I cannot find a good interpretation to explain the behavior. Does something have a suggestion for how it works?

Comment: Temporary cannot bind to non-const l-value reference.

Comment: Basically `(int)bb` is a prvalue which can't be bound to lvalue reference to non-const type.

Comment: when you get confused by templates, often it helps to write the code without templates and see whether it gets simpler. I dont think the template is actually relevant here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;**

`(int)bb` is [explicit type conversion](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast) and the result is an **prvalue** and a non-const lvalue reference such as `int&` cannot be bound to an prvalue.

---

> However, when I re-pack it to `int`. I select the template of const int&.

##### Case 1

Here we consider the call `func((int)bb, bbb)`.

Here the expression `(int)bb` is a **prvalue** of type `int`(and thus an **rvalue**) and since an rvalue cannot be bound to an *lvalue reference to non-const type*, the first overload `void func(const int& a1, f0& a2)` is the **only viable** option here.

That is, the first parameter `a1` of the second overload `void func(f0& a1, f1& a2)` is a *non-const lvalue reference which cannot be bound to an rvalue* and so the second overload is **not viable**. On the other hand, the first parameter `a1` of the first overload `void func(const int& a1, f0& a2)` is a *const lvalue reference which can be bound to an rvalue* and thus this first overload is **viable** and will be chosen.

This can be seen from [expr.cast#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#1):

> The result of the expression `(T) cast-expression` is of type `T`.
> The result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference to object type; **otherwise the result is a prvalue**.

(emphasis mine)

---

##### Case 2

Here we consider the call `func(static_cast<int>(bb), bbb);`

Here also the `static_cast<int>(bb)` is a prvalue and thus the first overload is the only viable option.